# Build laravel from framework kernel

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks, software-design

I have started a project to convert some parts of laravel framework to compiled php extensions to improve the performance. I have created a git repository for the migrated parts and another for the laravel modification that will use that extension.

My question is how to build completly all laravel from framework kernel modified?

Do you think that I'm doing well?

Comment: SO is for programming questions that _can preferably be answered in a few paragraphs_. This question is way to broad for this format.

Comment: I think that this covers a lot more than i think. I will focus in just the first question. Laravel has laravel repo (that contains framework) and framework repo. So maybe the right question is "how to make a build a functional laravel from framework kernel modified". I don't know if is necesary run some scripts or whatever and that's I would know.

Answer (score 1):

> I have started a project to convert some parts of laravel framework to
>   compiled php extensions to improve the performance
>
> ...
>
> My question is how to build completly all laravel from framework kernel modified?

Just don't. Laravel is a framework that is changing quite frequently and your attempts to make it working as native code will fail, because every composer update command call will force you to rebuild native implementation.

If you want to put heavy effort for performance optimisation, then go for other frameworks as Falcon, or use Lumen as an alternative (it's lightweight version of Laravel). That's all I can tell about Laravel itself, because optimisation have not only place in Laravel kernel, but also in database design, scale of the project, and other network configuration settings.

Provide more specific information about bottlenecks in your project, and you will get answers that you are looking for.

Comment: I know that is very active, and me and others know that to work on it.

Comment: @iLevi - Laravel is a framework that is heavily based on a lot of third party components (Symfony, FastRoute to name a couple). Are you planning on converting all those too and keep them up to date? That would require you to, more or less, constantly create updates and patches, Even if you would succeed. I actually don't think you would gain that much, if anything at all, by doing this.